# How to modify the batch file to get two last modified files from S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, batch-file, amazon-s3, cmd

I currently have a bat file that copies the last modified file from AWS S3 bucket to local folder.

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket example.sftp --prefix data/ --query "sort_by(Contents, &LastModified)[-1].Key" --output text') do set object=%%i
aws s3 cp s3://example.sftp/%object% E:\DATA_S3
```

I want to modify this to get two files when sorted by last modified instead of one. Changing `[-1]` to `[-2]` is not working.

Comment: `[-2]` simply refers to the second-last element in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a JMESPath query to get the two most recent items using `[-2:]`, and operate on each one in turn.  Note that in the path, instead of using `.Key`, use `.[Key]`, which causes AWS CLI's text output to delimit with newlines instead of tabs, allowing for easy parsing by the `for` operator of the batch file:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket example-bucket --prefix target/prefix/ --query "sort_by(Contents, &LastModified)[-2:].[Key]" --output text') do (
    aws s3 cp s3://example-bucket/%%i folder\to\copy\to
)
```

Answer (score 0):

JMESPath uses Python syntax for referencing lists, so use:

```
--query "sort_by(Contents, &LastModified)[-2:].Key"
```

This means "from the second last element to the end of the list".

I highly recommend the [JMESPath Tutorial](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html), which includes interactive testing of commands. I tested this concept using that page.